# Menu Options not working in tablet

Tags: android-menu

The menu options created are working perfectly fine in phone(both as overflow menu or left click device button).
But in tablet it only works on ones which have the overflow menu(the 3 dots).
When I click on the device left button nothing shows up. Not sure whats the problem

Layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings_menu"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_signout"
        android:title="@string/settings_sign_out"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, menu);
    settings = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings);
    signOut = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_signout);
return true;
}
```

Comment: check this and let me know if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841877/how-to-open-optionsmenu-on-tablet

Comment: No it didn't work :(